# Boost Spirit v2 gcc compilation error which does not show up using msvc

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I recently wrote some spirit parsing code in windows, which I recently have tried to get build on an ubuntu box and have ran into a compilation error that I am struggling with.

After some hacking and slashing, I have managed to come up with this example code snippet which exhibits the same behavior:

```
struct FooParser
: spirit::qi::grammar<
    std::string::const_iterator, 
    double(), 
    spirit::qi::ascii::space_type>
{
    FooParser() : FooParser::base_type(a_rule)
    {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        a_rule = double_;
    }

    spirit::qi::rule<
        string::const_iterator,
        double(),
        spirit::qi::ascii::space_type> a_rule;
};
```

which is then passed to a phrase_parse like so:

```
double result;
std::string txt;
FooParser foobar;
//...
if(phrase_parse(txt.begin(), txt.end(), foobar, space, result))
{
//do something
}
```

And when compiled, generates the following error:

```
boost/spirit/home/qi/reference.hpp:41: error: no matching function for call to 
‘boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char,
 std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, double(), 
boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, 
boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, 
boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type, 
boost::fusion::unused_type>::parse(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, 
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, const 
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> > >&, const boost::fusion::unused_type&, const 
boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, 
boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >&, double&) const’
```

The thing that I find frustrating is that visual studio seems more than happy to compile and run the code. I am hoping that the wise internets can show me where I have erred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is the `begin()` and `end()` of `std::string`, try this:

```
std::string::const_iterator begin = txt.begin();
std::string::const_iterator end = txt.end();
```

then pass that in:

```
phrase_parse(begin, end, foobar, space, result)
```

The problem I believe is that everywhere else you are using the type `const_iterator`, but `begin()`, `end()` on a non const string returns a normal iterator.

The key part of the error is this bit:

parse(__gnu_cxx::**__normal_iterator**, std::allocator > >&, const 
__gnu_cxx::**__normal_iterator**, 
std::allocator > >&

Comment: Ah, you are my hero! I am sad that after all this time I still don't understand type/const promotion in C++. On the other hand, I guess MSVC doesn't understand it either, so I shouldn't feel all that bad.

Comment: hehehe.. the problem is that such simple things are hidden in insanely complex error messages, it takes a while to decipher what is going on... :) I've done this in the past (and still continue to do so myself - if that's any consolation!) :)

Comment: @Voltaire: I'll never stop being amazed by the amount of programming errors that const correctness is able to catch.

Comment: `string::iterator` derives from `string::const_iterator` in the VC++ libraries, but it doesn't in gcc, at least not in the libs I've got - hence the results you see. I suppose according to taste you can think of this as VC++ needlessly catering for the usual sort of people that gcc users assume VC++ caters for, or the default gcc libraries being as absolutely annoying as the standard will permit (but no more, of course!), as you see fit ;)